# What happens when I access an array as uLong which was orignally declared as unsigned short?

Tags: c, arrays, types, casting

I have an array allocated by`malloc()`;initialised and declared like this:

```
unsigned short *array
```

Now if I'm sure the array is enough large:

```
(unsigned long)array[0]++
```

would work on the expected data length?
Would it cause an unaligned memory access *(which is susceptible to raise an exceptions on many architectures)*? It yes, would it be slower than accessing the variable several times with it's original type?

Is doing this is equal to :

```
for(int i=0;array[i]==0xFFFF || i==0;i++) { /// doing a uLong increment as per short members
    array[i]++
    if(i==(sizeof long)/2)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at operator precedence: The expression does not mean what you think. Order: subscript, postfix-increment, cast

Comment: Even when you get the syntax right this kind of code will have endian issues.  I don't think you will have unaligned access issues, it's a long time since the last IBM 360 shipped.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves : Yes, and the code run. That's why I'm asking the question : because I was unable to know the answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator I totally agree. I always had problems remembering about operator precedence. Nevermind, I figured it's equivalent to `(unsigned long) (array[2]++)`

Comment: if you are wanting to access an array of short as an array of long, then you will want to turn off strict aliasing in your compiler and setup some macros for endianness.

Comment: @technosaurus : What I should do for a little-endian machine?

Comment: @user2284570 If you aren't currently using one #error it and come back to it when it matters otherwise either every function that accesses them needs a LE counterpart or use a macro to use bitops to properly swap the uncommon case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(unsigned long)array[0]++
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(unsigned long)((array[0])++)
```

Not quite what you wanted, right?

Ok, answering your real question:
May I assign memory returned by `malloc` which I assigned to a `short*` to a `long*`?

`malloc()` is guaranteed to return space suitably aligned for any object.
So, for this part it does not matter that you first assigned it to a `unsigned short*`, instead of directly to a `unsigned long*`.

But there's another pitfall if you do so: Pointer aliasing rules mean if you access the same object as a `unsigned short` and as a `unsigned long`, you have *undefined bahavior*.

> #### 6.5 Expressions § 7
>
> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of
>   the following types:88)
>   — a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
>   — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>   — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
>   — a character type.

Many implementations have relaxed aliasing rules though, so you might be ok on yours.

Comment: Since you are saying it's ok, I tried my code with an array of 32 rows, and it appear the whole array is set to `1`. I don't have any idea why.

Comment: @user2284570: I said there are two aspects to the answer, and while the first issue is provably a non-issue, you have to decide on the second part for yourself, as we don't have anough context.

Answer (score 2):

This will not cause a problem, because the cast is applied after the data has been accessed as a `short`. Here is the sequence of operations that is going to happen:

- `array[2]`, a `short` value is accessed
- the value of `array[2]` is converted to `unsigned long`
- At the next sequence point, the `array[2]+1` value is stored in `array[2]`

This would not cause unalligned access, because there is no pointer cast.

**EDIT :** (in response to the edit of the question) Since `malloc` is guaranteed to return an array that is aligned for use with any type, your example with `array[0]` is guaranteed to work even if you cast the *pointer* to `unsigned long*`, assuming that you've got enough space for the data. However, it is not OK to access the same object both as `unsigned short` and as `unsigned long`.

Comment: I think I wasn't enough clear and you didn't understand what I wanted, so I updated the question.